# HashMap memory efficiency

Tags: java, memory-management, collections, hashmap

I am working on a Java web-application that uses one big cascade of hashmaps that looks like this:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double[]>>>
```

The construct is once created and then used read-only.

The double array has always exactly two elements. The problem I have is that in the end I use over 160 byte per double array. This is 10 times of what two doubles would use (each 8 byte).

I used `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` to look at memory usage once before the map was created and once after for these measurements.

How do I minimize memory overhead?

There are three possible solutions I consider right now:

- Use another data structure or hashmap implementation (which?)
- Exactly precalculate the size of each map and set initial capacity to this number + 1 and load factor to 1.0.
- Collapse all keys into one String by appending them. This is not very practical for me but absolutely doable. The code would look pretty bad though.

My question now is what is the best way to minimize memory overhead of a hashmap in my case where I create the hashmaps once and then only use them read-only?

Comment: What do your strings look like, and how many elements does each HashMap have on average? There may be some optimizations you can make based on these.

Comment: Is it possible to reduce that to a single HashMap by deriving a composite key?  Perhaps something as simple as concatenating the three key strings to make a single key would work.

Comment: @PaulHicks The asker mentioned that possibility.

Comment: It seems like the way to go.  No point in creating a new hashing colletion if the current one will work.  So long as you extract your key-creating logic to a reusable method, the application logic shouldn't look too bad.

Comment: My keys are between 8 and 64 characters long strings and it just occurred to me that they might consume much of the memory. The hashmaps have very different numbers of elements. I could in theory do two runs when creating the map: One for getting the sizes of the hashmaps and one for filling the hashmaps.

Comment: Yep, hash maps are very inefficient.  Each element is at least three objects, the entry itself, its key, and its value.  Even in the most compact JVM that's 48bytes (probably twice that), without even counting the hashtable array itself.

Comment: Note that it's the innermost HashMap that is consuming the lion's share of the storage (since there are so many of them).  Optimizing the outer HashMaps will not save you much.  In fact, attempting to do this could make things worse.

Answer (score 2):

Your description is a little confused, but I would:

1. Use a very high load factor such as 95%.
2. Make it `double[]` instead of `Double[]`

Comment: I tried you method and I get pretty decent results. At the moment I only use test data that is practically always the same values over and over again and I have very large jumps in memory usage. Can I tell java to not double the size each time the size limit is reached but rather only increase the size by half the current size?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to know all of the keys when calling `get()`, then I'd suggest creating a new object for the key. Remember to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`

**edit:**

Using an object over a concatenated will prevent key collisions with certian combinations.
If the strings are "AA", "BB" and "CC", and are concatenated to "AABBCC", then "A", "AB and "BCC" will be concatenated to the same value "AABBCC". Plus it is more readable code.

I have certainly concatenated Strings for keys in the past, but you have to be very careful.

You will lose a little space having this new object, but will save a considerable amount of space by reducing the number of Maps, many of which could be relatively empty.

Comment: Why? What do you have against `String`?

Comment: if the strings are "AA", "BB" and "CC", and are concatenated to "AABBCC", then "A", "AB and "BCC" will be concatenated to the same value "AABBCC". 
Plus it is more readable, something that the OP has noted

Comment: To avoid the concat issue, use some bizarre unicode char as a delimiter.  Any of your keys likely to have Armenian in them?

Answer (score 0):

Since this sounds like a static table -- not modified -- create the class:

```
public class MyValues {
    String key;
    double value1;
    double value2;
}
```

Create the objects and place in an array `MyValues[]`, then sort by the key.

Write a binary search algorithm to find values in the table.  (This is a very simple piece of code -- 20 lines or so.)

(Use regular HashMaps for the outer layers.)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that uses around 22 bytes per double array with the following method:

- Use double[] instead of Double[]
- I order the data I get by the first layer of keys and I used THashMap from the Trove library. This implementation of HashMap has a compact method that shrinks the size of a HashMap down to exactly the size it needs to hold all elements it has right now. By periodically calling this function I was able to constantly keep the size down.